# sql pivot table or something like a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to do a pivot table on two tables I have.

table 1

PersonToPhone

```
 PersonID int not null
 phoneID int not null
```

table2

Phone

```
phoneID int not null
PhoneNumber nvarchar(10)
PhoneType int
```

I would like the result to be

```
---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
personID | phoneNumber | phoneNumber | phoneNumber |........ n times
```

**is there a way of using a pivot table or some cool sql that will list a personID and all their phonenumbers on 1 row?**

Comment: Are all the phone numbers known ahead of time. If that's the case, you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) keyword.

Comment: The count of phoneIDs to personIDs will be 3

Comment: I am talking about knowing all the phone numbers. For example, do you know all 30 phone numbers for the 10 people so that you can specify the phone numbers as output columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select personID,[Foo],[Bar],[fooBar]
FROM (
        SELECT pp.PersonID,phonetype,phoneNumber 
        FROM personToPhone AS PP
        inner join phone as p on pp.phoneid = p.phoneid
        where pp.personid = @PersonID) as tableToPivot
pivot (max(phoneNumber) for phoneType IN ([[Foo],[Bar],[fooBar])) as pivotTable
```

Yanked most of the theory off of here
http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/dynamic-pivot/